# In Xamarin Visual Studio using C# how set UIButton to enabled in the C# code

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I have a UIButton object created in XIB and accessed via outlet in C# using Xamarin Studio. I also have a UITestField. I have set the UIButton state in the Attribute inspector to disabled. When the iPhone app runs and the text the user enters passes validation, I want to enable the UIButton (using my code) which is associated with a segue to the next screen in the app. 
How can I do this -- C# code please.

TIA

Comment: `UIButton` is derived from `UIControl`. Therefore, you should be able to set `UIControl.Enabled` to true to achieve your goal. http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIControl.Enabled

Answer (score 0):

UIButton state in the Attribute inspector is selector for customizing button appearance states.

To programmaticaly disable button you can use following code

```
buttonOutlet.Enabled = false;
```